# React Navigation stack navigator doesn't work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I used stackNavigator 2 in one of my projects as follows.
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

```
import {
   LoginScreen,
   TechStackScreen
} from '../screens';

// Public routes
export const PublicRoutes = StackNavigator({
   login: { screen: LoginScreen}
});

// Secured routes
export const SecuredRoutes = StackNavigator({
   techStack: { screen: TechStackScreen}
});
```

But when I tried to use it with version 3+ this doesn't work. Can anyone give me sample code of how to use stacknavigation 3+ like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `createAppContainer` on your root navigator. This was a [breaking](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/#explicit-app-container-required-for-the-root-navigator) change introduced in v3

Also `StackNavigator` has been replaced by `createStackNavigator`

Here is a simple example of the usage.

## `App.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AppContainer from './MainNavigation';
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    )
  }
}
```

## `MainNavigation.js`

```
import Screen1 from './Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen2';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

const screens = {
  Screen1: {
    screen: Screen1
  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2
  }
}

const config = {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Screen1'
}

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(screens,config);
export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should import and use `createStackNavigator`, here is the docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html

Just need a small change on your code

```js
// Public routes
export const PublicRoutes = createStackNavigator({
   login: { screen: LoginScreen}
});

// Secured routes
export const SecuredRoutes = createStackNavigator({
   techStack: { screen: TechStackScreen}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are using [StackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation), like this:

```html
// Inside "App.js"

render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer >
        <Stack.Navigator >
          <Stack.Screen name='Details'
                        component={ Details } />
        </Stack.Navigator >
      </NavigationContainer >
    )
}
```

You can use the navigation via accessing [properties](https://reactnative.dev/docs/props) available with each component:

```js
// Inside "Details" Component

export default class Details extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation

    return (
      <Button title='Goto Component' onPress={ () => navigate( 'SomeOtherComponent' ) }/>
    )
  }
}
```